# Convert python attr.ib using other values

Tags: python, python-attrs

I'm using the attrs library to create data structure for paths.
I want the first attribute to be the root directory which other are automatically joined with.
I'd like to have something like that:

```py
def my_converter(obj, value):
  return os.path.join(obj.root, value)

class Paths:
  root = attr.ib()
  relative = attr.ib(converter=my_converter)
```

This would do the trick, but `converter` function is given one argument only.
Is there a clean way to convert the value using other attributes before validation?
The `validator` takes three arguments (one of which is the object) but it is not the right place to convert values. Also putting everything into `__attrs_post_init__` defeats the purpose of using attrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a third attribute and a default:

```py
import os
import attr

@attr.s
class Paths:
  root = attr.ib()
  _relative = attr.ib(repr=False)
  full = attr.ib()

  @full.default
  def _full_factory(self):
     return os.path.join(self.root, self._relative)
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> Paths("/home", "foo")
Paths(root='/home', full='/home/foo')
```

I personally prefer straight-forward and well-named `@classmethod` factory methods in cases like this. They tend to be more readable and you can easily dodge them when writing tests.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, it will be useful for more complex fields where  reading from the data file takes place. As for now, for simple cases like converting paths I use validators.